# Calculate the domain of function

Tags: calculus, functions

I want to calculate the domain of

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{[x]^2-[x^2]}$$

To solve this suppose that

$x=n+a\quad$     s.t  $\quad n\in{Z}\,$ and $\,0 \le a < 1.$

Then
$$n^2=n^2+[2na+a^2] \Rightarrow [2na+a^2]=0 \Rightarrow 0\le 2na+a^2<1$$
How I can formulate this equation.

Comment: You have basically solved the problem. For each integer $n$, you may find the domain of $f$ inside the interval $[n, n + 1)$. The whole domain will be the union of these for all $n$.

Comment: What do the square brackets mean?